# Prevent Multiple Selections of Same Value but allow an value can multiple

Tags: jquery, validation

I want prevent multiple selections of same value but the value="others" only can multiple selection

my code is like this

```
function preventDupes( select, index ) {
var options = select.options,
    len = options.length;
while( len-- ) {
    //options[ len ].disabled = false;
}
//select.options[ index ].disabled = true;
if( index === select.selectedIndex ) {
    if(select.selectedIndex !== "Others"){
    if(select.selectedIndex != "") {
        alert('You\'ve already selected the item "' + select.options[index].text + '".\n\nPlease choose another.');
    }
    this.selectedIndex = 0; 
    }
} else if(index === "other") {



}
}

var f61 = select = document.getElementById( 'f61' );
var f62 = select = document.getElementById( 'f62' );
var f63 = select = document.getElementById( 'f63' );

f61.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, f62, this.selectedIndex );
    preventDupes.call(this, f63, this.selectedIndex );
};
f62.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, f61, this.selectedIndex );
    preventDupes.call(this, f63, this.selectedIndex );
};
f63.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, f62, this.selectedIndex );
    preventDupes.call(this, f61, this.selectedIndex );
};

<select name="indication_subject[]" id="f61">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Subject </option>
  <option value="Accounting"> Accounting</option>
  <option value="Afrikaans"> Afrikaans</option>
  <option value="Arabic"> Arabic</option>
  <option value="other">Others</option>
</select>
<select name="indication_subject[]" id="f61">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Subject </option>
  <option value="Accounting"> Accounting</option>
  <option value="Afrikaans"> Afrikaans</option>
  <option value="Arabic"> Arabic</option>
  <option value="other">Others</option>
</select>
<select name="indication_subject[]" id="f63">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Subject </option>
  <option value="Accounting"> Accounting</option>
  <option value="Afrikaans"> Afrikaans</option>
  <option value="Arabic"> Arabic</option>
  <option value="other">Others</option>
</select>
```

any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

JS is **case sensitive** as u said in question that `value="others"` and in your code  there is written

```
if(select.selectedIndex !== "Others")
```

check that and review

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript code you linked to, you might change

```
return $.inArray($(this).val(),arr)>-1;
```

to:

```
var value = $(this).val();
return $.inArray(value,arr)>-1 && value != 'other';
```

In your code, there is a bug.

```
if(select.selectedIndex !== "Others"){
```

`.selectedIndex` is the integer index of the selected element, not a string. Instead, you probably want `.value`. You should read the documentation on the [HTML `select` element's DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement).